# Generate gen folder for new create package folder

Tags: android, import, package, r.java-file

I'm working on a project, I have all the clases on the same package, lets suppose: "com.example.project".

But now I'm getting with many classes so I would like to classify them in packages as for example: "com.example.project.bluetooth", "com.example.project.dialer", etc...

So, to do this, I created a new package the same way I would create a new class. But when created, all the classes inside of it have error with all the R imports. I see this is because in the gen folder, there isn't no reference to the new package.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You create new package and paste necessary classes in it ?

Comment: Yes. Sure that I do it wrong way or I forgot to add something, but don't now what

Comment: You are getting error in import statements ? please check it.

Comment: "R cannot be resolved to a variable" it gives me the option to import R from android, or from my original package

Comment: Yes import yourpackagename.R not android.R.

Comment: Glad to help you. Happy codding :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should import `yourpackageName.R` instead of `android.R`.
 Hope it helps.

> Note: Eclipse sometimes likes to add an "import android.R" statement
>   at the top of your files that use resources, especially when you ask
>   Eclipse to sort or otherwise manage imports. This will cause your make
>   to break. Look out for these erroneous import statements and delete
>   them.*

Replace

```
import android.R;
```

with

```
import com.example.myapp.R;
```